# How to resize Swing JButon's icon

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton

I have a icon that i want to use on a JButton and somewhere else, using other dimensions. So is there any way i can resize (like `button.setIconSize(124, 124);` the same icon while not having 2 of them?

Comment: Icons are painted at their actual size, so if you want different sized icons then you need to create multiple icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("picture_Path"); //unscaled image
Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(newWidth, newHeight, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); // resize it here
imageIcon = new ImageIcon(newimg);  // transform it back
```

so it would go something like

```
JButton.setIcon(imageIcon(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

Icons are painted at their actual size, so if you want different sized icons then you need to create multiple icons. The preferred size of the component you add the Icon to will always be based on the size of the Icon.

If you want the ability to have an `Icon` dynamically scale as the size of its parent component resizes then you can use the [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/).

Comment: Am I right in saying that the actual clickable area of a JButton is derived from the layout manager being used?

Comment: @DonnachaConnolly The clickable area is derived from the actual size of the button, which can be controlled by the layout manager, but can be influenced by the button through `getPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize`